# Getting Booleans and Integers from strings.xml

Tags: java, android

I've only ever had to work with Strings within the strings.xml file before, but now I have a case where I need to work with Boolean and Integer items.

`<item type="integer" name="usenetPort">563</item>`

`<item type="bool" name="usenetUseSSL">true</item>`

I usually use `getResources().getString(R.strings.my_string)` to retrieve a value, but that doesn't work with Boolean and Integers. I tried `getInteger()` and `getBoolean()` but Eclipse says that's wrong.

How do I get the value from Booleans and Integers?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It works for me, first I openned Strings.xml and added this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <item type="integer" name="mynumber">4</item>
</resources>
```

Then in the code I get the value by doing this:

```
int number= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mynumber);
```

**You have to use R.integer.* and not R.string.***

Comment: Ah, got it. `R.integer` and `R.bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Activity class

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.some_int_value);
getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.some_bool_value);
```